# Add logic hooks to on demand sugar crm professional

Tags: sugarcrm

Ok so i just purchased a new sugarcrm professional instance on sugarcrm and I would like to add some custom logic to my leads. I would like to add them to an external service (mailchimp) through their api. ive seen that I have to create some custom php files, but I dont know how to upload them to my instance, and how is the structure of that upload. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your Hook and subsequently created the installation package to install using Module Loader. Try to follow the guidance that you find here [Creating an Installable Package for a Logic Hook](http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/03_Developers/Module_Loader/Examples/Creating_an_Installable_Package_for_a_Logic_Hook)

Comment: I wanted to add records to the database using the logic hook. What is the procedure for that?